# Problem with getting javascript answer after a subscription button

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I'm doing a form with one field: a password form. When I submit it, I just want the JavaScript to tell the user if the password is the good one or if he has to try again.
Here's my code:

```
var x = document.forms["CodeForm"]["email"].value;
if (x == "MAX") {
    $message._show('success', '✅ Code Correct !');
} else {
    $message._show('failure', '❌ Code Incorrect !');
}
```

As you see, the "succes" and "failure" parts are for my CSS class who tells the script the color of the text just after. Now, my problem is when I enter anything, the "if" part works and it says "Code Incorrect !" in red (as I want) but if I enter the good code just after, it says "Code Correct" but in red, and not in green as it is in the CSS class "success". When I enter the good code first (after reloading the page) then it's in green.

If you wanna try it, here's my website, and the good code is "MAX" : http://enigma-door.000webhostapp.com

Here are the html code for the form and the `_show` method:

```
<form name="CodeForm" id="signup-form" method="post" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Code" />
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
</form>
```

```
$message._show = function(type, text) {
    $message.innerHTML = text;
    $message.classList.add(type);
    $message.classList.add('visible');

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $message._hide();
    }, 3000);
};
```

Comment: Can you show me your HTML code?

Comment: my html form code is :
`<form name="CodeForm" id="signup-form" method="post" action="#">
 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Code" />
 <input type="submit" value="Valider" />
</form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your $message._show method please remove the existing class then it will work.`$message.classList.remove("failure");`
Since your failure css class is not removed it is having high specificity and overriding for success [image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to know for sure without seeing the `_show` method, but it sounds like perhaps you're not removing the `.failure` class when you're adding the `.success` class.

The way to find out is to inspect the html using chrome's dev tools and see what classes your input has. That will tell you why it's red.

Comment: The show method is :
`$message._show = function(type, text) {`
 `$message.innerHTML = text;`
 `$message.classList.add(type);`
 `$message.classList.add('visible');`

 `window.setTimeout(function() {`
  `$message._hide();`
 `}, 3000);`

`};``